# How to get internal & external url data using Mozscape API?

Tags: c#

I am using C# wrapper for [SEOmoz API](https://github.com/PixelMEDIA/SEOMozLib). The internal/external data which is displayed in open site explorer. How to get this data using this API?

```
var moz = new Mozscape() { MozAccessId = "xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx", MozSecretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", MozApiType = MozAPI.URL_METRICS };
var url = moz.CreateMozAPIUrl("webmetro.com", MozAPI.URL_METRICS, 1);
var results = moz.GetUrlMetrics(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozscape Link Metrics is used for internal and external data.

To get Internal Data.

```
var moz = new Mozscape() { MozAccessId = MozAccessID, MozSecretKey = MozSecretKEY, MozApiType = MozAPI.LINK_SCAPE };
var url = moz.CreateMozAPIUrl_LinkMetrics(DomainName, MozAPI.LINK_SCAPE, 1, Scope.page_to_domain);
var FullIntUrl = url + "&Filter=internal&Sort=page_authority&SourceCols=103079217573&TargetCols=4&Limit=1000";
var Intr = moz.GetLinkMetrics(FullIntUrl);
```

To get External data.

```
  var FullExtUrl = url + "&Filter=external&Sort=page_authority&SourceCols=103079217573&TargetCols=4&Limit=1000";
   var Extr = moz.GetLinkMetrics(FullExtUrl);
```

Comment: I need the same thing in PHP, but i am lost. Can anyone help me with that.

Comment: Nothing just a blank array returns, i just need the final url which is stored in FullIntUrl, so that i can be sure what i doing wrong.

Comment: can we discuss on skype? My id is "musakkhir".